# Getting Push-Notifications, even when the app is killed

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android

Our app uses a server that can send out push notifications to a phone. But it can only do that, while the app is at least in the background. As soon as it is killed as a background task ( from the task manager) the notifications will no longer be delivered. But how is for instance WhatsApp doing that? When I am closing whatsapp from the task manager, I still get notified about incoming messages.

Well, I though maybe a background service would help me out so this is what I have done so far:

```
private void StartServiceForPushs()
{
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, typeof(Activity_MainMenu));
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.GetService(this, 0, intent, 0);
    AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager)GetSystemService(Context.AlarmService);
    alarm.SetRepeating(AlarmType.RtcWakeup, TimeUtils.CurrentTimeMillis(), 1 * 60000, pendingIntent);
}
```

This should set up a service that checks for push notifications every 1 minute - but unfortunately, it does nothing. As soon as the app is closed completely, there are no more incomming messages. Can anyone help me out here?

Comment: by using a push nottification server check this out https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/data-cloud/google-messaging/firebase-cloud-messaging or this https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/xamarin-sdk-setup

Comment: You can use GCM to send notification.

Comment: i am, but still the app needs to be open to receive them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I managaed to solve that isse - it is actually quite simple. Just write a service that returns a sticky Start Command Result like this:

```
[Service]
    public class BackgroundService : Service
    {

        static readonly string TAG = "X:" + typeof(Activity_MainMenu).Name;

        static readonly int DELAY_BETWEEN_LOG_MESSAGES = 5000;
        static readonly int NOTIFICATION_ID = 10000;

        UtcTimestamper timestamper;
        Handler handler;
        Action runnable;

        public override void OnCreate()
        {
            base.OnCreate();


            timestamper = new UtcTimestamper();
            handler = new Handler();

            runnable = new Action(() =>
            {
                if (timestamper != null)
                {
                    handler.PostDelayed(runnable, DELAY_BETWEEN_LOG_MESSAGES);
                }
            });
        }

        public override StartCommandResult OnStartCommand(Intent intent, StartCommandFlags flags, int startId) // HIER DRIN MUSS GECALLED WERDEN!
        {
            DispatchNotificationThatServiceIsRunning();
            return StartCommandResult.Sticky;
        }

        public override IBinder OnBind(Intent intent)
        {
            return null;
        }

        public override void OnDestroy()
        {
            base.OnDestroy();
            OnCreate();
        }


        void DispatchNotificationThatServiceIsRunning()
        {
            Notification.Builder notificationBuilder = new Notification.Builder(this)
                .SetSmallIcon(Resource.Drawable.btn_bookoflifeMainMenu)
                .SetContentTitle(Resources.GetString(Resource.String.app_name))
                .SetContentText("TESTING");

            var notificationManager = (NotificationManager)GetSystemService(NotificationService);
            notificationManager.Notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, notificationBuilder.Build());
        }


    }
```

And then start your service from any activity in you app ( such as the main menu ).

This will keep the app forever running in the background - but after a restart of the phone, the app would need to be restarted I guess.

Comment: `StartCommandResult.Sticky` just try to keep your `Service` alive, then your process 's priority will be higher than normal, but your app still can be killed by system when low memory, you app can't run in background forever. You can test it on different phone.